# In the following is Hobbes paraphrasing Aristotle?

Tags: metaphysics, aristotle, hobbes

In Hobbes *Leviathan, chapter II: The imagination* he writes:

That when a thing lies still, unless somewhat else stirs it, it will lie still forever, is a truth no man doubts of. But that when a thing is in motion, it will be eternally in motion, unless somewhat else stay it, though the reason be the same, that nothing an change itself, is not so easily assented to.

Is this something that he gets from Aristotle?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On the contrary, he's paraphrasing Galileo's refutation of Aristotle, i.e. Galileo's law of inertia: an object in motion will remain in motion unless compelled to stop by an outside influence.

Comment: of course; For some reason I thought Galileo was born after Hobbes...